# Check if JSON key is present

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I have a function downloading JSON. It does it fine however in some cases a object may not contain a certain key. On that occasion it still trys to add a value to the array. I want to make it so if the key is not present then a value of nil is added to the array. Would appreciate it if someone could help. Thanks alot.

```
if let link = itemDict.value(forKey: "link") {
    if link != nil {
        self.linkArray.append(link as! String)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you were using Decodable properly this would just happen all by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do not use the force unwrapping. Also your `if let` is wrong for what you want to achieve. Copy paste version:

```
let link = itemDict.value(forKey: "link") as? String
self.linkArray.append(link)
```

Comment: I get this error 'Value of optional type 'String?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?'. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It means that `linkArray` accepts only Non-Optional Strings. If you want to store nil values there just change the implementation of this array to something like this: `var linkArray: [String?]`

Comment: Glad to help :)